# How to have the output of a JS function put into a p tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have the following HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/javascript" href="FileContainingJS">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="Stuff"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following JS code:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I want the result of the HelloWorld function to go in the p tag (yielding a paragraph with "Hello World". Any help would be greatly appreciated :) 
P.S. Ignore minor syntax errors because I'm rushing xD

Comment: This process is called DOM manipulation. Please google it and checkout Javascript DOM apis and post your attempted solutions.

Comment: I tried using document.getElementById('stuff').innerHTML=HelloWorld() with no success.

Comment: @FrankieD. because the id is `Stuff` with a capital `S`.

Answer (score 2):

This is called DOM manipulation -- as others has mentioned. What you do, is you take a JavaScript object the represents an element in your HTML document, and you modify a property or call a method to manipulate it.

Here, you want to change the text within it. The `innerHTML` property allows you to set the HTML inside the `p` tag to whatever you want. That's your first option.

Your second option is to use the `textContent` property, now this works like the `innerHTML` property, but it avoids problems like XSS attacks: you can't inject HTML using this property.

I recommend the second option due to the aforementioned security advantage.

Now, let's find ways to get the object representing your paragraph element. The way you would do this is by taking an existing object, representing the *entire document* and then selecting a child of it using methods.

This pre-existing object, built into JavaScript, is `document`. Now, to grab an element with a certain ID, you can call its method of `getElementById(id)`. That's the method I recommend.

Other methods to grab your paragraph object could be `getElementByQuerySelector(cssSelector)` which requires a CSS selector (in this case `#stuff`.

So, our final solution would be:

```
document // our whole document
        .getElementById("Stuff") // just our paragraph
                                .textContent // what's inside it
                                             = helloWorld() // result of funct.
```

In one line, this looks like

```
document.getElementById("Stuff").textContent = helloWorld();
```

A note as well:

- Starting your IDs with a capital letter is unusual. In JavaScript, people usually write in camelCase, where the first word starts with a lowercase letter, and any subsequent words each begin with a capital letter (e.g. `iLikeToEatCows`). Having this consistency allows programmers to hear "Okay so the ID is myparagraph" and be able to write `myParagraph` with quite a bit of certainty. But of course, this is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by doing the following:

```
function HelloWorld() {
  document.getElementById('Stuff').innerHTML = 'Hello World';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called DOM manipulation. The most simple way to insert the text "Hello World" (or any text) would be with `.innerHTML`

```
var result = HelloWorld();
document.getElementById("Stuff").innerHTML = result;
```